# How to populate data in a combobox based on the data from another textbox in vba

Tags: excel, vba

So I have this problem where I want to populate data in combobox where it has reference data.

Here is my table from excel:

[image: Sample Data]

And here is my form:

[image]

So when the user will input **100** in `textbox` like in the image above, only `alex herd` and `Diana Edmunds` will be available for dropdown and selection in `Party Name` combobox. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you didn't add own code, I content myself only to the core facts of your post demonstrating an approach using the dynamic array features of **MS 365** via the `Filter()` function, organized in a `Let`-function container which allows a clear structure avoiding some redundancies and enables to define expressions ("variables") together with their contents in pairs of arguments.

**Needed steps**

You are referring to an existing data sheet (assuming columns A:C), so
try the following steps:

- Write your textbox value into a named cell (e.g. `$D$1`, named "Number"),
- Enter the following formula into cell $D$2:

```
=LET(data,FILTER(A:B,C:C=Number), FName,INDEX(data,,1), LName,INDEX(data,,2), PROPER(FName& " " & LName))
```

This formula writes the wanted names dynamically to a so called *spill range* which can be referenced by a "#"-suffix (e.g. by `D2#`)

[image: Data]

- Eventually you can use the `TextBox1_Change` event to assign the entire data set to the `.List` property of your combobox:

```
     ComboBox1.List = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("D2#").Value ' << change to needed sheet name
```